# validating a xml doc in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, xsd

I have a xml object in Groovy.. that has already been parsed by the time I get to it

```
def doc = new XmlSlurper().parse('sample.xml')
```

I want to validate it against an XSD

However in the example code for this involves the xml being presented in string or file

```
def xsdLocation = 'defn.xsd'
SchemaFactory.newInstance( XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
   .newSchema( new File(xsdLocation))
   .newValidator()
   .validate(  doc  )
```

I can't figure out what conversion or combination of StreamSource type object I need to pass in what I have (result of XmlSlurper.parse) to validate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def doc = new XmlSlurper().parse('sample.xml') 

def xsdLocation = 'defn.xsd'

SchemaFactory.newInstance( XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
   .newSchema( new File(xsdLocation))
   .newValidator()
   .validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader( XmlUtil.serialize(doc))))
```